# Other Alternative for FFMPEG

Tags: php, video, upload

I am developing a video streaming web app, written in PHP. I uploaded my videos in Amazon S3, and I want to extract a thumbnail from the video to be use as preview. My hosting is HostGator and as far as I know, they do not support FFMPEG on shared server, so is there any other alternatives for FFMPEG? If somebody here have bypassed and get the FFMPEG working on HostGator, answer will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you're already using AWS S3, you might take a look at AWS [Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/?nc1=h_l2_as)

Comment: Oh, i have not checked it yet, but does it acts as an alternative to FFMPEG?

Comment: It can certainly do most of the things that ffmpeg does, probably actually uses ffmpeg behind the scenes

Comment: http://zencoder.com/en/ is another similar service. I've used them and they're quite good. Any shared host that doesn't allow ffmpeg isn't going to allow an alternative - their concern is the CPU usage, not the specific tool.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go for your own vps instead of searching for shared ffmpeg hosting. As far as I know ffmpeg on shared environment can be quite resource consuming process. On your own vps you get the option to install and configure ffmpeg as per your requirements.